# How to make circular tabs in the body of scaffold?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Following is my mock:

[image: mock]

Here I seek help trying to make the circular tabs, the divider line with space available for body of tabs.

Tried this:
https://mightytechno.com/style-tabs-in-flutter-app/

(1st option but still no circle)

Comment: why not use a hack.... create the widget yourself.. First create circle component with Container then to use PageView for the swaping

Comment: you can then use onTap function on each circle widget to move the PageView Controller..

Comment: Can you share code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Your TabView Controller, something like this

```
TabController _tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
```

Your Body would be like

```
body :  ListView(
//Your TabBar would be something like this, not exactly

new TabBar (children:[
   new Column(children:[
      CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new Image.asset('asset_location'),),
      Text('menu_item_name')
   ]),
   new Column(children:[
      CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new Image.asset('asset_location'),),
      Text('menu_item_name')
   ]),
   new Column(children:[
      CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new Image.asset('asset_location'),),
      Text('menu_item_name')
   ]),
]),

// Then your TabVieW starts here
Your TabView(controller: _tabController,
    children:[
    new Container(child: new Text('Tab1')) // Tab 1
    new Container(child: new Text('Tab2')) // Tab 2
    new Container(child: new Text('Tab3')) // Tab 3
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html) Widget inside the Tab widget.

Or check if this might help [bubble_tab_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble_tab_indicator#-readme-tab-).